# How to import ZXing library into my os x swift app?

Tags: macos, swift, zxing

Okay,

I'm new to xcode development and I'd like to use the

https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC

library in my swift os x app. I followed the instructions from here:

[Importing 3rd party library ZXing into Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22818745/importing-3rd-party-library-zxing-into-xcode?rq=1)

First I downloaded it from github and added it to my project (right-click on my project->add Files to "myProject"). How described by clicking 'ZXingObjC.xcodeproj'. I added libZXingObjC-osx.a to "linked frameworks and libraries" and the font is red colored. Then I added the path to header and library search paths.

It compiles fine. But I cannot get access to the library. How can I use this library?

Thanks

Comment: Use cocoapods - it's described in "Installation" and it's by far the easiest way to install libs

Comment: Thank you, after installing ZXingObjC with cocoapods I see a new project called Pods and there are all required *.h and *.m   But how can I access these classes within my swift class?

Comment: You should `#include` one or more header files in your bridge file - I think it should be `#import <ZXingObjC/ZXingObjC.h>`, but not sure

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. I had to do #import "ZXingObjC/ZXingObjC.h". Double quotes instead of angle brackets...